# Agrupar y sumar datos de un CSV con Bash o AWK

Tags: bash, bucle-for, shell-script, awk, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo un archivo CSV con la estructura siguiente:

```
country,year,sex,age,suicides_no,population,suicides/100k pop,country-year,HDI for year, gdp_for_year ($) ,gdp_per_capita ($),generation
Albania,1987,male,15-24 years,21,312900,6.71,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Albania,1987,male,35-54 years,16,308000,5.19,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Silent
Albania,1987,female,15-24 years,14,289700,4.83,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Albania,1987,male,75+ years,1,21800,4.59,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Albania,1987,male,25-34 years,9,274300,3.28,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Boomers
Albania,1987,female,75+ years,1,35600,2.81,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Albania,1987,female,35-54 years,6,278800,2.15,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Silent
Albania,1987,female,25-34 years,4,257200,1.56,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Boomers
Albania,1987,male,55-74 years,1,137500,0.73,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Albania,1987,female,5-14 years,0,311000,0,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Albania,1987,female,55-74 years,0,144600,0,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Albania,1987,male,5-14 years,0,338200,0,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Albania,1988,female,75+ years,2,36400,5.49,Albania1988,,2126000000,769,G.I. Generation
Albania,1988,male,15-24 years,17,319200,5.33,Albania1988,,2126000000,769,Generation X
```

Estoy intentando realizar un script con un bucle for para obtener el número de suicidios por país, año y sexo. Por ahora, el bucle que he hecho es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Primero, guardamos en varios CSV las los países, años y sexo.

tail -n +2 suicidios_final.csv | cut -d "," -f1 | sort | uniq > country.csv
tail -n +2 suicidios_final.csv | cut -d "," -f2 | sort | uniq > year.csv
tail -n +2 suicidios_final.csv | cut -d "," -f3 | sort | uniq > sex.csv

# Creamos arrays de las las variables anteriores mediante el comando mapfile:

mapfile -t countries < country.csv
mapfile -t years < year.csv
mapfile -t sex < sex.csv

# Finalmente, realizamos la iteración mediante un bucle for para los países, otro bucle for anidado para los años y un tercero para el sexo.
# Además, añadiremos un color diferente para cada una de las variables, para distinguirlas bien:

for i in "${countries[@]}"; do
 echo -e "\e[36m== $i ==\e[0m"
 for j in "${years[@]}"; do
  echo -e "     \e[33m$j\e[0m"
  for k in "${sex[@]}"; do
   echo -e "     \e[31m$k\e[0m"  
   tail -n +2 suicidios_final.csv | grep -F "$i" | grep -F "$j" | grep -F "$k" > bucle.csv
   suicidios=$(cat bucle.csv | cut -d "," -f5 | paste -s -d "+" | bc)
   echo -e "      \e[34mNúmero de suicidios: $suicidios\e[0m"
  done
 done
done
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar el script la salida que obtengo no es la deseada, pues el bucle realiza las sumas de los suicidios para la categoría "female" de la variable sex correctamente, pero para la categoría "male" lo que está haciendo es sumar las filas independientemente de que sea "male" o "female":

```
./script.sh

== Albania ==
     1985
     female
      Número de suicidios: 15
     male
      Número de suicidios: 50
     1986
     female
      Número de suicidios: 
     male
      Número de suicidios: 
     1987
     female
      Número de suicidios: 25
     male
      Número de suicidios: 73
     1988
     female
      Número de suicidios: 22
     male
      Número de suicidios: 63
     1989
     female
      Número de suicidios: 15
     male
      Número de suicidios: 68
     1990
     female
      Número de suicidios: 
     male
      Número de suicidios: 
     1991
     female
      Número de suicidios: 
     male
      Número de suicidios: 
     1992
     female
      Número de suicidios: 14
     male
      Número de suicidios: 47
     1993
     female
      Número de suicidios: 27
     male
      Número de suicidios: 73
     1994
     female
      Número de suicidios: 15
     male
      Número de suicidios: 50
     1995
     female
      Número de suicidios: 34
     male
      Número de suicidios: 88
     1996
     female
      Número de suicidios: 39
     male
      Número de suicidios: 89

             ......
```

Realmente, en el primer resultado ya obtengo errores, porque no tengo datos para Albania en el año 1985, pero me he fijado en el resultado de otros países distintos en diversos años y no veo que se produzca este tipo de error, por lo que entiendo que el error puede ser de los propios datos del fichero. Independientemente, el error que no entiendo es el de la variable sex, pues en el apartado de la categoría "female" sí que hace la suma de suicidios correctamente, pero luego para "male" me da la suma tanto de los casos de "male" como de "female". Sé que es un tanto difícil mi pregunta porque se trata de un bucle for anidado tres veces y no resultará fácil ver un error a primera vista, pero si alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando y me lo dice lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: ¿Y si usas Awk directamente y usas las tres primeras columnas como índice? `awk -F, '{a[$1 $2 $3]+=$5} END{for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' fichero`.

Comment: Hola @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', el código que me dices sirve pero los datos aparecen juntos. Por ejemplo: Albania1987Hombre 48. ¿Habría manera de que aparecieran separados? Igualemente, estaba intentando realizar un bucle for normal más que nada para probarme un poco. Igual escogí un bucle un tanto difícil...

Comment: No creo que Bash sea la mejor herramienta para conseguirlo. Por supuesto que se puede, pero no lo considero tan útil como otras. Ej. python, R, etc.

Comment: @Cuauhtli tienes razón. Finalmente veo que con awk es mucho más práctico. Lo que, como le comenté a fedorqui, en la salida que obtengo con el código que me sugirió me aparece todo junto. Voy a ver si consigo arreglarlo para que me salga cada valor por separado. Gracias a los dos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replantee tu problema de dos maneras distintas; la primera usando GNU Datamash, y la segunda con un script de `awk`.

El archivo ejemplo sobre el que lo tomé es este al que el llamé `suicidios_final.csv`:

```
country,year,sex,age,suicides_no,population,suicides/100k pop,country-year,HDI for year, gdp_for_year ($) ,gdp_per_capita ($),generation
Albania,1987,male,15-24 years,21,312900,6.71,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Albania,1988,male,35-54 years,16,308000,5.19,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Silent
Albania,1988,female,15-24 years,14,289700,4.83,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Albania,1987,male,75+ years,1,21800,4.59,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Albania,1987,male,25-34 years,9,274300,3.28,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Boomers
Albania,1987,female,75+ years,1,35600,2.81,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Albania,1989,female,35-54 years,6,278800,2.15,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Silent
Albania,1987,female,25-34 years,4,257200,1.56,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,Boomers
Albania,1987,male,55-74 years,1,137500,0.73,Albania1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
México,1987,female,5-14 years,0,311000,0,México1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
México,1989,female,55-74 years,0,144600,0,México1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
México,1989,male,5-14 years,0,338200,0,México1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
México,1988,female,75+ years,2,36400,5.49,México1988,,2126000000,769,G.I. Generation
México,1988,male,15-24 years,17,319200,5.33,México1988,,2126000000,769,Generation X
México,1988,male,15-24 years,17,319200,5.33,México1988,,2126000000,769,Generation X
Colombia,1988,male,15-24 years,17,319200,5.33,Colombia1988,,2126000000,769,Generation X
Colombia,1987,female,5-14 years,0,311000,0,Colombia1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Colombia,1967,female,55-74 years,0,144600,0,Colombia1987,,2156624900,796,G.I. Generation
Colombia,1957,male,5-14 years,0,338200,0,Colombia1987,,2156624900,796,Generation X
Colombia,1988,female,75+ years,2,36400,5.49,Colombia1988,,2126000000,769,G.I. Generation
Colombia,1988,male,15-24 years,17,319200,5.33,Colombia1988,,2126000000,769,Generation X
Colombia,1988,male,15-24 years,17,319200,5.33,Colombia1988,,2126000000,769,Generation X
Colombia,1988,male,15-24 years,17,319200,5.33,Colombia1988,,2126000000,769,Generation X
```

## Con `datamash`

En una sola línea:

```
$ datamash --sort -t , -H -g 1,2,3 sum 5 < suicidios_final.csv | column -t -s ,
```

Donde le pido a datamash que agrupe por los campos 1,2,3, y luego que sume el campo 5 utilizando como separador el caracter ",".

Resultando en:

```
GroupBy(country)  GroupBy(year)  GroupBy(sex)  sum(suicides_no)
Albania           1987           female        5
Albania           1987           male          32
Albania           1988           female        14
Albania           1988           male          16
Albania           1989           female        6
Colombia          1957           male          0
Colombia          1967           female        0
Colombia          1987           female        0
Colombia          1988           female        2
Colombia          1988           male          68
México            1987           female        0
México            1988           female        2
México            1988           male          34
México            1989           female        0
México            1989           male          0
```

Si no tienes `datamash`, instalalo con `sudo apt install datamash`.

## Usando `awk`

Aquí tan sólo mezclé [este script](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Walking-Arrays) que viene en la documentación oficial para mostrar ("caminar" a través de) el contenido de un array multidimensional.

Luego utilicé los respectivos campos asignándolos como claves del array. Así, `awk` se encarga de hacer todo el trabajo, ya que no pueden haber claves repetidas en un array, por lo que la agrupación se realiza de forma automática debido a la naturaleza de las claves del array, y la suma tan sólo la indicamos con el operador `+=` sobre el quinto campo.

En un archivo llamado `main.awk`, ponemos el siguiente contenido:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

# 1. Country
# 2. Year
# 3. Sex
# 4. Age
# 5. Suicides No

function walk_array(arr, name, i) {
    for (i in arr) {
        if (isarray(arr[i]))
            walk_array(arr[i], (name "[" i "]"))
        else
            printf("%s[%s] = %s\n", name, i, arr[i])
    }
}
# Aquí nos saltamos el primer renglón
NR!=1{
    reporte[$1][$2][$3]+=$5
}
END {       
    walk_array(reporte,"Reporte: ")
}
```

Y en la terminal corremos:

```
$ awk -f main.awk -F , suicidios_final.csv
```

Obteniendo:

```
Reporte: [México][1987][female] = 0
Reporte: [México][1988][male] = 34
Reporte: [México][1988][female] = 2
Reporte: [México][1989][male] = 0
Reporte: [México][1989][female] = 0
Reporte: [Albania][1987][female] = 5
Reporte: [Albania][1987][male] = 32
Reporte: [Albania][1988][female] = 14
Reporte: [Albania][1988][male] = 16
Reporte: [Albania][1989][female] = 6
Reporte: [Colombia][1957][male] = 0
Reporte: [Colombia][1967][female] = 0
Reporte: [Colombia][1987][female] = 0
Reporte: [Colombia][1988][female] = 2
Reporte: [Colombia][1988][male] = 68
```

### Nota:

Usar una gran mezcla de herramientas de GNU/Linux puede ser tentador los primeros años, pero es súmamente ineficiente (y muy poco estético), ya que cada programa abre descriptores de archivos, luego los cierra, pueden crear programas temporales que luego eliminará. Hay que tener en cuenta que no se puede usar Bash a la ligera como si fuera un lenguaje de programación, sino una gran herramienta para orquestar programas.

Por esto es mejor utilizar únicamente utilidades dedicadas a la tarea que querramos o poderosos lenguajes como `sed`, `awk`, `python`, `perl`, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias Cuauhtli!! Probaré ambas posibilidades!! Saludos!